# How can I update pom.xml in jenkins pipeline without having developer to change his pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Objective: I need to add rpm-maven-plugin dependency in the original pom.xml in a jenkins pipeline

Reason: Developer don't have to worry about packaging the jar into rpm, moreover there are 100's of microservices cannot make changes to all the pom.xml's.

Any input is appreciated,

I have followed along this [post](https://github.com/davelms/medium-articles/tree/master/spring-maven-rpm)

I need to update the existing pom.xml in jenkins pipeline to be able to add the rpm-maven-plugin on the fly, without having to commit to code base.

Comment: To define plugins, one usually defines a company parent POM from which everyone inherits. This way everyone gets the necessary plugins in the right versions.

Comment: Simple answer to this: Not possible. Changing jar to rpm is a fundamental change in deployment also ... simply added to package into rpm is not enough. You have to give different configuration options where the jar will be located in the rpm (target system) etc. etc. ?

Comment: Yeah as a Build of the jar is coming from various teams that is a uphill battle to fight, they are not going to change the source code, it has to be done by automation team in Jenkins,

Comment: I suppose to introduce a company parent POM and tell everyone to use it. After some kind you can introduce a step in Jenkins that will fail the build unless it has the correct parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins pipelines support the steps [`readMavenPom`:](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readmavenpom-read-a-maven-project-file)

> Reads a Maven project file. The returned object is a Model.

and [`writeMavenPom`:](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writemavenpom-write-a-maven-project-file)

> Writes a Maven project file. That for example was previously read by `readMavenPom`.